# Create new element with one button effectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

i'm trying to create printable polaroid template, but i have a problem with some element, i have sticker container like this :

```
     <div class="sticker-container">
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (1).gif"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (2).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (3).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (4).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (5).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (6).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (7).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (8).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (9).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (10).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (11).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (12).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (13).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (14).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (15).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (16).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (17).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (18).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (19).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (20).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (21).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (22).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (23).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (24).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (25).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (26).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-4/MermaidTropics (27).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (1).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (2).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (3).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (4).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (5).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (6).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (7).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (8).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (9).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (10).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (11).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (12).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (13).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (14).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (15).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (16).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (17).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (18).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (19).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (20).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (21).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (22).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (23).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (24).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (25).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (26).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (27).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (28).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (29).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (30).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (31).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (32).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (33).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (34).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (35).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (36).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (37).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (38).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (39).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (40).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (41).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (42).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (43).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (44).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (45).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (46).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (47).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (48).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (49).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-1/LuuCreativeColors (50).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/1.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/2.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/3.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/4.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/5.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/6.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/7.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/8.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/9.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/10.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/11.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/12.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/13.gif"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/14.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/15.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/16.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/17.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/18.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/19.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/20.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/21.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/22.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/23.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/24.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/25.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/26.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/27.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/28.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/29.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/30.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/31.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/32.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/33.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/34.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/35.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/36.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/37.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/38.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/39.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/40.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/41.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/42.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/43.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/44.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/45.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/46.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/47.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/48.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/49.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-2/50.png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-3/Emoji Face by Waatt (1).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-3/Emoji Face by Waatt (2).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-3/Emoji Face by Waatt (3).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-3/Emoji Face by Waatt (4).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-3/Emoji Face by Waatt (5).png"/></div>
      <div class="sticker"><img src="ssts/img/overlay-3/Emoji Face by Waatt (6).png"/></div>
    </div>
```

the screenshot of `sticker container` :

[image]

when i click the picture it will create new element to the `polaroid-container`, here :

[image]

My problem is, how to make its work ? i tried to use this code :

```
    var counter = 0;
      $('.sticker').on("click", function() {
        $('.cutting-container').append("<div class='sticker-body'><img src='ssts/img/overlay-3/Emoji Face by Waatt (6).png'/></div>");
        $('.sticker-body').draggable({
          containment: $('.polaroid')
        });
      });`
```

but it will only show one image that i write on `.append()` , how to make this effectively without create `jquery` each image ?

**UPDATE**

[image]

full page. As you can see with this code :

```
    var counter = 0;
      $('.sticker').on("click", function() {
        $('.cutting-container').append("<div class='sticker-body'><img src='ssts/img/overlay-3/Emoji Face by Waatt (6).png'/></div>");
        $('.sticker-body').draggable({
          containment: $('.polaroid')
        });
      });
```

it will create new element on `polaroid-container` called `sticker-body` and it will come with image inside `append()`. I have class called `sticker` its for `sticker image`, what i want is when i click `sticker class` with `ex: image-1` it will show `image-1` and if its another `sticker class` it will show `image-2`

how do i create this more effectively without create jquery each `id` (*if i use id per class) ? So i should not create a lot of 'append()` code. Thanks

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for that ?

Comment: How `sticker image` and `cutting-container image` is related?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Is full page screenshot enough ? Cause i can't write a fiddle of it..

Comment: @Satpal `cutting-container` is for `html2canvas` so dont' mind it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are having bunch of stickers that user can select from a template container and add them to another div.

Here is what I have done:

1. I made a new object. So you are going to deal with a complete new object.
2. I made it draggable.

```js
var counter = 0;


$('.sticker').on("click", function() {
  let $sticker = $($(this).html()); // use a cloned object in case you want to eliminate it.
  $('.cutting-container').append($sticker);
   $sticker.draggable({
     containment: $('.polaroid')
   });
 
});
```

Comment: where's the `sticker-body` goes ? This class is for make the `sticker` absolute and will cloning inside `polaroid`, your code let the `sticker` show outside `polaroid`, can you help me a little fix of it ? thanks

Comment: I tried to use `sticker-body` inside `append()` but it show `[object object]` not the image

Comment: I created an object of the clicked object.

Comment: How do i resize it after cloned ? it show full page image

Comment: Aww thanks, i made it, thanks for your help i just need to add `div` to `html` thanks a lot sir :D

Comment: One more last sir, how to make this `resizable` ?

Comment: You are welcome! BTW, I am not sure what you mean by "resizable". Would you like to make it bigger or the user can adjust the size?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138975/discussion-between-ahbagheri-and-gilang-rizkie).